# How to have a specific number of rows in table

Tags: css, angular, html-table

I have a table that contains a list of persons. I populated the table using *ngfor.

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let person of people (click)="addThisPersonToArray(person)" [class.active]="isPersonSelected(person)">
        <td>{{person.id}}</td>
        <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
       <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Each row of the table is a person. Let's say I want only 10 rows to be visible in the table. Let's say the number of person in the list is 5 person the remaining 5 rows will be blank but still visible to the view. If persons in the list is greater than 10 then the table will overflorw/scrollable. Basically this is I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason why just making the height of the table tall enough to hold ten rows won't work, along with `overflow-x: scroll`? I can't see what this has to do with Angular.

Comment: @torazaburo Actually I have two tables in which data can be transferred from one table to the other. I want that two table to have the same height/ number of rows regardless of how many number of data in both tables. I just set the numbers of rows visible to 10.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your expectation

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <table class="table1"> 
    <tr *ngFor="let person of people" (click)="addThisPersonToArray(person)">
      <td>{{person.first_name}}</td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    <div style="max-height:100px;overflow:scroll"> 
    <table class="second-case">
    <tr *ngFor="let person of second" (click)="addThisPersonToArray(person)">
      <td>{{person.first_name}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  people:any[]=[{"first_name":"Sara"},{"first_name":"Harry"},{"first_name":"Eugene"},{"first_name":"Julia"},{"first_name":"Barbara"}];
  second:any[]=[{"first_name":"Frank"},{"first_name":"Harry"},{"first_name":"Joshua"},{"first_name":"Julia"},{"first_name":"Louis"},{"first_name":"Patrick"},{"first_name":"Paul"},{"first_name":"Joyce"},{"first_name":"Brenda"},{"first_name":"Joshua"},{"first_name":"Jerry"},{"first_name":"Janet"},{"first_name":"Nicholas"},{"first_name":"Janet"},{"first_name":"Julia"}];
  constructor() {
    if(this.people.length<10){
      let temp = {"first_name": ""};
      for(let i=this.people.length; i<10; i++ ){
        let temp = {"first_name": ""};
        this.people.push(temp);
      }
  }
  }
}
```

Handling the scroll in css

```
tr td{
  border : 1px solid blue;
}
.table1 tr td{
  height :20px;
}

.second-case {
  height:80px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Let me know if you need any explanations

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/XAwlOHdWPOs1LNl8bALh?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks for your help. I now able to set the blank rows but everytime I transfer data to the other table the data pushed at the end of the table. The blank rows is at the top while the pushed data is at the end